# reading file with "[" and manipulation each line TCL

Tags: tcl

I have file with the below lines **(file.list)**:

```
insert_buffer [get_ports { port }] BUFF1 -new_net  net -new_cell cell
```

I'm reading the file with the below script **(read.tcl)**:

```
    #! /usr/local/bin/tclsh
foreach arg $argv {

set file [open $arg r]
set data [ read $file ]

foreach line  [ split $data "\n" ] {

puts $line

set name [lindex $line [expr [lsearch -all $line "-new_cell"]+1]]
puts $name
}

close $file

}
```

while running the above script **(read.tcl file.list)** I get error since I have "[" in file.list and script think its a beginning of TCL command.

```
list element in braces followed by "]" instead of space
    while executing
"lsearch -all $line "-new_cell""
    ("foreach" body line 5)
    invoked from within
"foreach line  [ split $data "\n" ] {
```

How can I read the file correctly and overcome the **"["** symbol?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I read the file correctly and overcome the "[" symbol?

I don't really understand why you are doing what you are doing (processing one Tcl script by another), but you have to make sure that each line is a valid Tcl list before submitting it to `lsearch`.

```
lsearch -all [split $line] "-new_cell"
```

Only `split` will turn an arbitrary string (containing characters special to Tcl) into a valid Tcl list.

Comment: Do I need to use split in lsearch even if It used in the reading file?

Comment: Your first `split` produces a list of lines, a second `split` is needed to turn each line string into a list of line elements; so yes.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the few times in Tcl that you need to worry about what *type* of data you have. `$line` holds a **string**. *Don't use list commands on strings* because there's no guarantee that an arbitrary string is a well-formed list.

Do this:

```
set fields [split $line]
# don't use "-all" here: you want a single index, not a list of indices.
set idx [lsearch -exact $fields "-new_cell"]
if {$idx == -1} {
    do something here if there's no -new_cell in the line
} else {
    set name [lindex $fields $idx+1]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to apply a list operation on the variable, it has to be a valid list. The variable `$line` is not a valid list.

It is better to use `regexp` rather than `lsearch`

```
regexp -- {-new_cell\s+(\S+)} $x match value
puts $value
```

**Output :**

```
cell
```